# Can I get a view if I know the group position and child position?

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

Is it possible to do something like this pseudo code?

```
View v = findView(groupPosition, childPosition)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the logic is possible , take a look in the webSite of android about :

`ViewGroup.getChildAt(index);`

and :

```
ViewGroup.getChildCount();
```

Answer (score -1):

Well make a function that returns a `View` object.

```
public View findView(g, c){

     //do something with g and c

     return v_obj; // a `View` object
}
```

Comment: Ok...but is that logic possible? How do I get the view object from g an c?